# How do I only validate against one specific button using ParsleyJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have applied ParsleyJS validation to a form that has multiple submit buttons that perform various tasks. I only want the validation to occur for one of the submit buttons, is this possible? if so, how?

For a pared down example:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="page.aspx" id="aspnetForm" data-validate="parsley">
    <input type="text" id="text_for_example" data-required="true"/>
    <input type="text" id="text_for_example2" data-required="true"/>
    <input type="text" id="text_for_example3" />
    <input type="submit" id="ClearsTheTextBoxes"/>
    <input type="submit" id="SavesData" />
</form>
```

Ideally I want it to validate only on the "SavesData" submit, not on the "ClearsTheTextsBoxes". is this possible using ParsleyJS?

Thanks!

Note:
I cannot change the type any of the submit buttons to function differently; please do not suggest this. The "ClearsTheTextsBoxes" must remain a submit button.

Answer (score 2):

to do so, you'll have to remove `data-validate="parsley"` from your form tag, and add a custom js function on `click` on the desired button. Then in this function, simply to a $('aspenetForm').parsley('validate');

Best